# MySQL silly query plan

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm using 5.6.15-56-log Percona Server. Here's my table(which has over 5M records)

```
 CREATE TABLE `promotion_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `template_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,    
  `gain_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
  UNIQUE KEY `index_promotion_codes_on_code` (`code`),    
  KEY `index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id` (`template_id`,`gain_user_id`),    
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5995895 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query 1 (took 0.00 sec, looks fine):

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
    +----+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                           | key                                     | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | ref  | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | 10      | const,const | 33088 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Query 2 (took 4.46 sec, what the hell?)

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id asc limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | index | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  137 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Obviously MySQL did a full table scan so that it took over 4 seconds. And the query time when I force using the index is sane (0.01 sec)

```
select * from promotion_codes use index (index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id) where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id asc limit 1;
```

Query 3 (took 0.09 sec, oh my)

```
select * from promotion_codes where template_id = 443 and gain_user_id is null order by id desc limit 1;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | promotion_codes | index | index_promotion_codes_on_t_id_and_gu_id | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  138 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The explain result is identical to query 2(order by id asc vs order by id desc), however the time it took is far different.

So I have several questions:

1. Why not use the index when `order by id`, using that index reduces the rows to scan from over 5M to 30K, so there's just no way that MySQL should ignore that index.
2. What does the `rows` column mean in the explain? I always thought it was how many rows MySQL thinks it should scan to get the result, if I'm correct, that in query 2, the `137` is too wrong(the number in query 3 doesn't make sense either).